# Anchor Link To An Anchor Tag On Another Page Does Not Work

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, anchor, permalinks

Information: 
**Self Hosted WordPress Site**
*Testing on local host using Uniserver as well as the Test site and pre-production site hosted on the company's local servers rather than FTP.*
**Issue**

- Created several Anchor Tags on one page
- Linked to said Anchor Tags via a list on another page.

Anchor Link Code:

```
<a id="anchorlink1"></a>
<a href="http://fullurlhere/nbs-test-panel-of-diseases-2#anchorlink1">link text</a>
```

I also tried:

```
<a name="anchorlink1"></a>
<a href="http://fullurlhere/nbs-test-panel-of-diseases-2#anchorlink1">link text</a>
```

And:

```
<a name="anchorlink1"></a>
<a href="/nbs-test-panel-of-diseases-2#anchorlink1">link text</a>
```

And

```
<a name="anchorlink1"></a>
<a href="http://fullurlhere/nbs-test-panel-of-diseases-2/#anchorlink1">link text</a>
```

**Result:**
When a user clicks the link to the Anchor Link on a different page, the address bar will display the full url with the Anchor Link for a second then the Anchor Link will be removed and only the root URL to the page will be displayed.

Example:
Displays for a second:

```
http://fullurlhere/nbs-test-panel-of-diseases-2#anchorlink1
```

Then it will revert to this:

```
http://fullurlhere/nbs-test-panel-of-diseases-2
```

Troubleshooting:
I have done the following trouble shooting all with no effect:

- Commented out this code in the .httaccess file: **RewriteBase /**
- Updated the Settings/Permalinks to remove the **/**
- Installed the TinyMCE Plugin that inserts Anchor Tags to make sure that I was adding the correctly.
- Tried ID rather than Name
- Moved the Anchor Tag from the inside the H4 tag to outside of it, before and after and in front of the paragraph and outside to see if that would have an effect. (it did not)
- Tried linking from inside the page, rather than to the page. This worked like it should.
- Copy and pasted the full URL into the address bar. That worked too.
- Also tried linking to a div and heading id. It seems that anything with a # in front of it is simply removed from the url.
- Changed the WordPress theme to a default theme and the issue was not present.

It appears that this issue only happens when I link to the Anchor Tag from a different page.

**I have narrowed down the issue to the jquery.jstree.js file**.

Not sure how to fix it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok so scratch that, that fix worked for the anchor link but caused a problem with the menu. It no longer stayed open...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```
<a name="anchorlink1"></a>
<a id="anchorlink1" href="http://fullurlhere/nbs-test-panel-of-diseases-2#anchorlink1">link text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from the question

> JHP 11/7/13
>   We discovered that the issue was a specific code in the
>   js file. There were six instances in it and once we removed them
>   everything worked fine.
>
> ```
> .replace(/^#/,"")
> ```